# C# Moving programatically through rich textbox without cuting lines

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox, measure

I am doing a WinForms application with image/page scheme (the user is navigating between images by clicking at particular areas of the image). At one page I made rich textbox in which I wanted to load "rules" for the user to accept. Unfortunatelly, the rules are longer than the RTB, so I had to apply some kind of scrolling. I didn't want to let the user use a scrollbar - instead I made two buttons (up & down) by which the user can slide through the rules - user cant select or move text in any other way. Everything works great apart from one thing - after clicking the button, the text slides but part of the 1st and last shown lines are being cut (only part of the height of line is visible in rtb).

Below I list the code used for making such RTB (named "rules"):

```
                rules.Clear(); 
                rules.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                rules.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Vertical;
                rules.ReadOnly = true;
                rules.KeyPress += rules_KeyPress;
                rules.SelectionChanged += rules_SelectionChanged;
                rules.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(450*this.Width/2000, 550*this.Height/1125);
                Console.WriteLine(rules.Font);
                float size = 16.5F;
                rules.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", size);
                Console.WriteLine(rules.Font);
                using (Graphics g = rules.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    rules_line_height = Convert.ToInt32(g.MeasureString("A", rules.Font).Height); //getting the measure of the line
                    Console.WriteLine(rules_line_height);
                }
                int rules_h = 400 * this.Height / 1125; //height of the rtb
                int lines_n = rules_h / rules_line_height; //max number of lines that can be fit in the height
                rules.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000 * this.Width / 2000, lines_n*rules_line_height); //height of the rtb adjusted to fill full lines
                rules.ForeColor = Color.White;
                string fileName = "reg_pl.txt";
                string line = "";
                StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/reg/" + fileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250"));
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    rules.AppendText(line + "\r\n");
                }
                file.Close();
                rules_max = rules.GetMaxRange(); //getting max range of the rtb
                rules_thumb = rules.GetThumb(); //getting size of visible part of the rtb
                rules_loc = 0; // current location visible part compared to the whole rtb
                rules.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
                rules.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                rules.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(18, 25, 56);
                rules.BringToFront();
```

I also used the custom_RTB class for getting max range and thumb of the RTB and scrolling to selected point of the RTB :

```
    public class CustomRTB : System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
{
    #region API Stuff

    public struct SCROLLINFO
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public int fMask;
        public int min;
        public int max;
        public int nPage;
        public int nPos;
        public int nTrackPos;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar, int nPos, bool bRedraw);

    [DllImport("User32.Dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA")]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int GetScrollInfo(IntPtr hwnd, int nBar,
                                       ref SCROLLINFO scrollInfo);
    private const int SB_HORZ = 0x0;
    private const int SB_VERT = 0x1;
    #endregion
    public int HorizontalPosition
    {
        get { return GetScrollPos((IntPtr)this.Handle, SB_HORZ); }
        set { SetScrollPos((IntPtr)this.Handle, SB_HORZ, value, true); }
    }

    public int VerticalPosition
    {
        get { return GetScrollPos((IntPtr)this.Handle, SB_VERT); }
        set { SetScrollPos((IntPtr)this.Handle, SB_VERT, value, true); }
    }

    public void ScrollTo(int Position)
    {
        SetScrollPos((IntPtr)this.Handle, 0x1, Position, true);
        PostMessage((IntPtr)this.Handle, 0x115, 4 + 0x10000 * Position, 0);
    }


    public int GetMaxRange()
    {
        SCROLLINFO scrollInfo = new SCROLLINFO();
        scrollInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(scrollInfo);
        //SIF_RANGE = 0x1, SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10,  SIF_PAGE= 0x2
        scrollInfo.fMask = 0x10 | 0x1 | 0x2;
        GetScrollInfo((IntPtr)this.Handle, 1, ref scrollInfo);//nBar = 1 -> VScrollbar
        return scrollInfo.max;
    }

    public int GetThumb()
    {
        SCROLLINFO scrollInfo = new SCROLLINFO();
        scrollInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(scrollInfo);
        //SIF_RANGE = 0x1, SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10,  SIF_PAGE= 0x2
        scrollInfo.fMask = 0x10 | 0x1 | 0x2;
        GetScrollInfo((IntPtr)this.Handle, 1, ref scrollInfo);//nBar = 1 -> VScrollbar
        return scrollInfo.nPage;
    }

    public int GetCurPos()
    {
        SCROLLINFO scrollInfo = new SCROLLINFO();
        scrollInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(scrollInfo);
        //SIF_RANGE = 0x1, SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10,  SIF_PAGE= 0x2
        scrollInfo.fMask = 0x10 | 0x1 | 0x2;
        GetScrollInfo((IntPtr)this.Handle, 1, ref scrollInfo);//nBar = 1 -> VScrollbar
        return scrollInfo.nTrackPos;
    }

    public bool ReachedBottom()
    {
        SCROLLINFO scrollInfo = new SCROLLINFO();
        scrollInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(scrollInfo);
        //SIF_RANGE = 0x1, SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10,  SIF_PAGE= 0x2
        scrollInfo.fMask = 0x10 | 0x1 | 0x2;
        GetScrollInfo((IntPtr)this.Handle, 1, ref scrollInfo);//nBar = 1 -> VScrollbar
        return scrollInfo.max == scrollInfo.nTrackPos + scrollInfo.nPage;
    }

}
```

And here are the "buttons" for moving the text up:

```
                int lines = rules_thumb / rules_line_height; //getting max number of lines that can be visible
                int new_thumb = lines * rules_line_height; //getting the move value so the lines won't be cut

                if (rules_loc - (new_thumb) >= 0) //if moving by the move value will be still over 0, then proceed normally
                {
                    rules_loc -= (new_thumb);
                    rules.ScrollTo(rules_loc);
                }
                else // if it will pass 0, the move to 0
                {
                    rules_loc = 0;
                    rules.ScrollTo(rules_loc);
                }
```

And down :

```
                int lines = rules_thumb / rules_line_height;
                int new_thumb = lines * rules_line_height;

                if (rules_loc + (new_thumb) < rules_max)
                {
                    rules_loc += (new_thumb);
                    rules.ScrollTo(rules_loc);
                }
                else
                {
                    rules.ScrollTo(rules_max);
                }
```

What I think I am doing wrong is measuring the lines heigh at given font and setting the good size for the RTB. Does anyone had similar problem and can somehow assist me with it?

Thank you in advance for the answer.

Best regards,
Sarachiel

Comment: Try changing `g.MeasureString()` with `rules_line_height = TextRenderer.MeasureText(rules.CreateGraphics(), "AgTMp", rules.Font, rules.Size, TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl).Height;`

Comment: Well, that was cryptic. That string, "AgTMp", means you have to measure the actual text, with both upper and lower cases. Fonts may have some peculiar design. If you need to measure a sample, maybe "SgMpW" is a better one.

Comment: Thank you both for the help, this one solved my problem :) Checked the measure difference. With g.MeasureString() it gave me 28 height, while with the MeasureText it gave 26. Works like charm, thanks a lot !:)